# Boost CCM PFC inductor current

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost, power-factor-correction

Does anyone know how to use Mathcad to draw the boost PFC inductor current waveform?

There is no equation to tell me how to do it, so I am confused.
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/InfineonApplicationNote_PFCCCMBoostConverterDesignGuide-AN-v02_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624a56eed8014a62c75a923b05

[image]

Update :

After following Antonio51, I draw one figure. but I don't know how many offset I should add to become CCM waveform.

[image]

Comment: Only to make the picture? For case 2 & 3, divide in some intervals, then just write a "linear" function ... which amplitude is modulated by a sine function at the last point of "line". For case 1, it is around a sine.

Comment: @Antonio51, I only know how to draw the red line, but I don't know how to express the blue line, can you give me an example?

Comment: The slope of the blue rising line is determined by the voltage input (a rectified sinewave). The blue falling slope is determined by the difference between output voltage (usually about 400 volts) and the input voltage. I don't use mathcad so I can't help further.

Comment: @Jitter456 your update/addition has fallen into the same trap as Antonio's answer; the rising slope looks pretty good but the falling slope is not right. And, if you do the calculations properly you'll find that the charge/discharge cycle time gets longer when the input voltage is higher.

Comment: HI @Andyaka,

Sorry, could you give me an example?
I don't get it. where I do wrong.

Comment: @Andyaka I use different slop to draw this figure.

Comment: @Andyaka :-) I said ...  if it was for "drawing" only the picture "approximately". It is not what one gets ... when one simulates the circuits that give these waveforms ...

Comment: @Jitter456 - the concavity of the downward slope should mirror the concavity of the upward slope. Generally, the downward slope should be shallower as the input voltage rises. I can't say more than that without giving a full answer and I haven't got the details to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that these pictures are the "results" of 3 different PFC behavior.

Case 2 :
Here is an **"approximative"** doing ...
You can use the same idea for other pictures.

[image]

Case 1 & 2 :

[image]

In the "real" world ... , case 1, for example, is the "behavior" of this circuit ... and it is not as "beautiful" ...

[image]

Comment: The trouble is that it's a slight bit more complex than what you have shown. Valiant effort on the variation in slope for the rising part of the waveform but, the falling part of the waveform need to have the correct variability too; it's slope is highest when Vin is near 0 volts and grows shallower as Vin rises towards Vout (a constant). I think precision is what is being asked for here.

Comment: May I know why VTsin2 need to use V2,V3 and VTsin?

Comment: I update a figure on it.

Comment: @Jitter456 VTsin2 may probably be "simplified". V3 makes an amplification of Vsin by a factor of 4 and then is added to VTsin making a "same picture" as OP case 1 (just to be approximately the same "appearance", not a real "behavior" of PFC. See my updated answer with a real PFC example (not really the same "picture").

Answer (score 1):

Just reproduce the signals as mathematical functions. You have the modulating signal, which is a sine, and the carrier, which is a triangular waveform of some sort (ramp, triangle, asymmetrical triangle, etc). For the sine, it's easy (I'll use wxMaxima since I am more familiar with it, and because I don't have Mathcad, but you can see the similarities):

```
s(t):=0.9*sin(2*%pi*f*t)$
```

For the carrier, if it's a 50% triangle:

```
c(t):=asin(sin(2*%pi*f*t))*2/%pi$
```

where `f` is the signal's frequency. For a more generic approach you can't avoid discontinuities:

```
base(t):=if t<a then t/a else 1-(t-a)/(1-a)$
c(t):=base(mod(t*fs,1),a)$
```

where `fc` is the carrier's frequency. All there's needed is to plot the signals: `s(t)` (red), `c(t)` (green), and `if s(t)>c(t) then 0.99 else 0.01` (not 0 and 1 for better viewing, blue). For example, an asymmetric carrier with \$\alpha=0.7\$ with a sampling frequency 10x greater:

[image: PWM in wxMaxima]

Comment: Well, I got stuck on the PWM side of it but, if you really want switching waveforms then you need to use the PWM output with a convolution, you'll get exponential rising/falling slopes. But it's a little bit more complicated than the above...